# What is the savart unit in Persian music theory?

Tags: intervals, temperament, intonation

I was heard about `Savart` unit in Persian music that divides a chromatic interval into smaller units.

Persian musicians using an interval smaller than the chromatic intervals, called: Kron. they measure it using the `Savart` unit.

is this true?
if is true, then how can I convert it into cent or vise-versa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An article by Joe Monzo at http://tonalsoft.com/enc/s/savart.aspx defines the savart as 1/300 of an octave.

> A savart is calculated as the 300th root of 2, or 2(1/300), with a
>   ratio of approximately 1:1.002313162. It is an irrational number. A
>   savart has an interval size of approximately 4 cents.

```
savart = 1000log10(f2/f1)
cents = 1200log2(f2/f1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Cents, as the name implies, are 1/100th of a semitone (or "chromatic interval"), when working in 12-tone equal temperment (12-TET).

So, as long as your definition of "savar" is in relation to a "chromatic interval" that is defined as a 12th of an octave, then you should be able to convert back and forth by simply defining `1 savar = 2 cents`.

However, if the Persian chromatic interval is not 1/12 of an octave, you will have to draw an equivalence in relation to the octave. The cent is 1/1200th of an octave. The savar is 1/(50**c*) of an octave, where *c* is the number of equal chromatic intervals that make up an octave. You can then easily compare the two.

Comment: I couldn't find any references to `savar` beyond your question, but [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rec.music.iranian/qX_0ibaM_2o) seems to indicate a scale that is not strictly equal-tempered, though it may be based on choosing certain 24-TET notes to end up with 17 unequal tones.

Comment: yes, in persian called savar, but i just found the true spell, savart

Comment: @pylover I see your edits--does this mean the Persian chromatic interval is 1/6 of an octave?

Comment: no. we have a concept named: dastgah. so the intervals are variable across dastgah.for example, in dastgah: shoor ,E-F is 20 savar.

Comment: @NReilingh It takes its name from the French physicist Savart. See Jean During's article for instance: Théories et pratiques de la gamme iranienne. https://www.jstor.org/stable/928594.